# Append count var after html (heart var) - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code below:

```
heart.html("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign'></i>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;"+count);
```

i want the count element outside the heart.html(). something like:

```
heart.html("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign'></i>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;")+count;
```

heart is a click able div and I don't want the count to be clickable.

**whole code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery('body').on('click','.jm-post-like',function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        heart = jQuery(this);
        post_id = heart.data("post_id");
        heart.html("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></i>");
        jQuery.ajax
        ({
            type: "post",
            url: ajax_var.url,
            data: "action=jm-post-like&nonce="+ajax_var.nonce+"&jm_post_like=&post_id="+post_id,
            success: function(count)
            {
                if( count.indexOf( "already" ) !== -1 )
                {
                    var lecount = count.replace("already","");
                    if (lecount === "0")
                    {
                        lecount = "0";
                    }
                    heart.prop('title', 'Like');
                    heart.removeClass("liked");
                    heart.html("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'></i>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;"+lecount);
                }
                else
                {
                    heart.prop('title', 'Unlike');
                    heart.addClass("liked");
                    heart.html("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign'></i>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;"+count);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});

function getPostLikeLink( $post_id )
{
   $like_count = get_post_meta( $post_id, "_post_like_count", true ); // Get post likes.
   $count = ( empty( $like_count ) || $like_count == "0" ) ? '0' : esc_attr( $like_count );
   if ( AlreadyLiked( $post_id ) )
   {
        $class = esc_attr( ' liked' );
        $title = esc_attr( 'Unlike' );
        $heart = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></i>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;';
   }
   else
   {
        $class = esc_attr( '' );
        $title = esc_attr( 'Like' );
        $heart = '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;';
   }
   $output = '<a href="#" class="jm-post-like'.$class.'" data-post_id="'.$post_id.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$heart.'&nbsp;</a>'.$count;
   return $output;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```
heart.html("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign'></i>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;")
heart.after(count);
```

but if you call the script multiple times, the numbers will keep prepending instead of getting overriden... so

```
heart.html("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign'></i>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;");
var $counter = heart.next('.counter');
if (!$counter.length) {
    $counter = $('<span />', {
        'class': 'counter'
    }).insertAfter(heart);
}
$counter.html(count);
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I just tried this. count is not showing. i am checking my code again to see what's causing the problem.

Comment: @user3266957 if you had tried the second method there were few issues in it... now updated... also see [first method](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/chobju1r/3/) and [second method](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/chobju1r/6/)